# java - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on my web application

Tags: java, aplicación-web, struts

Estoy queriendo desplegar mi aplicación web basada en `Struts2`, y tengo el siguiente error en los navegadores.

En **Internet Explorer**, me sale esto:

[image: Error lanzado en Internet Explorer]

Y en **Google Chrome**, me sale lo siguiente:

[image: Error lanzado en Google Chrome]

Y ya no puedo seguir modificando mi aplicación web, si es que no puedo acceder a ella. El IDE que estoy usando es `sts-3.8.4.RELEASE`, y el servidor de aplicaciones que uso es el que vino por defecto con el IDE, que es `Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.2`. Lo estoy usando, porque no demora nada en desplegar las aplicaciones web.

El enlace es http://localhost:8080/Pasteleria/

Y el código de mi `index.jsp` es:

```
<%@ page import="pe.com.pasteleria.util.Parametros" %>
<%@ page import="pe.com.pasteleria.util.Sesion" %>
<%
response.sendRedirect(Sesion.getInstance().get(Parametros.SESION_USUARIO) == null ? "InicioSesion.jsp" : "Inicio.jsp");
%>
```

`Inicio.jsp`:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sb" uri="/struts-bootstrap-tags"%>
<%@ page import="pe.com.pasteleria.entitybean.Usuario" %>
<%@ page import="pe.com.pasteleria.util.Parametros" %>
<%@ page import="pe.com.pasteleria.util.Sesion" %>
<%
if (Sesion.getInstance().get(Parametros.SESION_USUARIO) == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("InicioSesion.jsp");
}
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Blue Moon - Responsive Admin Dashboard</title>
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="blitzer"></sj:head>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
    name="viewport">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="../../html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

<!--  jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Isolated Version of Bootstrap, not needed if your site already uses Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" />

<!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                var date_input = $('input[name="usrFecNac"]');
                var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $(
                        '.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
                var options = {
                    format : 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                    container : container,
                    todayHighlight : true,
                    autoclose : true,
                };
                date_input.datepicker(options);
            })
</script>

<link href="Bootstrap/icomoon/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="Bootstrap/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a class="logo"> <img src="Bootstrap/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
        </a>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="dashboard-container">
            <div class="top-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.jsp"> <span class="icon-home-3"></span>
                            Principal
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="Productos.jsp"> <span class="icon-food"></span>
                            Productos
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="Perfil.jsp"> <span
                            class="icon-user-3"></span>
                            Mi perfil
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="Empresa.jsp"> <span class="icon-office"></span>
                            Nosotros
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="Ayuda.jsp"> <span
                            class="icon-question"></span>
                            Ayuda
                    </a></li>
                    <%
                    if (Sesion.getInstance().get(Parametros.SESION_USUARIO) != null && 
                    ((Usuario) Sesion.getInstance().get(Parametros.SESION_USUARIO)).getIdTipoUsuario().equals(1)) {
                    %>
                    <li><a href="Trabajadores.jsp"> <span
                            class="icon-user-4"></span>
                            Trabajadores
                    </a></li>
                    <%
                    }
                    %>
                    <%
                    if (Sesion.getInstance().get(Parametros.SESION_USUARIO) != null && 
                    ((Usuario) Sesion.getInstance().get(Parametros.SESION_USUARIO)).getIdTipoUsuario().equals(1)) {
                    %>
                    <li><a href="Consultas.jsp"> <span
                            class="icon-star"></span>
                            Consultas
                    </a></li>
                    <%
                    }
                    %>
                    <%
                    if (Sesion.getInstance().get(Parametros.SESION_USUARIO) != null) {
                    %>
                    <li><a href="CerrarSesion.jsp"> <span
                            class="icon-question"></span>
                            Cerrar Sesion
                    </a></li>
                    <%
                    }
                    %>
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="dashboard-wrapper">
                <div class="left-sidebar">
                    <h1>¡Bienvenido!</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`InicioSesion.jsp`:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sb" uri="/struts-bootstrap-tags"%>
<%@ page import="pe.com.pasteleria.entitybean.Usuario" %>
<%@ page import="pe.com.pasteleria.util.Parametros" %>
<%@ page import="pe.com.pasteleria.util.Sesion" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bienvenidos a pastelería a domicilio</title>
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="blitzer"></sj:head>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
    name="viewport">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="../../html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<link href="Bootstrap/icomoon/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="Bootstrap/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a class="logo"> <img src="Bootstrap/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
        </a>
    </header>
    <s:actionerror theme="bootstrap" />
    <s:actionmessage theme="bootstrap" />
    <s:fielderror theme="bootstrap" />
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="dashboard-container">
            <div class="top-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.jsp"> <span class="icon-home-3"></span>
                            Principal
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="Productos.jsp"> <span class="icon-food"></span>
                            Productos
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="RegistroUsuario.jsp"> <span
                            class="icon-user-3"></span>
                            Registrarme
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="Empresa.jsp"> <span class="icon-office"></span>
                            Nosotros
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="Ayuda.jsp"> <span
                            class="icon-question"></span>
                            Ayuda
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a><span class="icon-user-4"></span>
                            Inicie sesión
                    </a></li>
                    <%
                    if (Sesion.getInstance().get(Parametros.SESION_USUARIO) != null && 
                    ((Usuario) Sesion.getInstance().get(Parametros.SESION_USUARIO)).getIdTipoUsuario().equals(1)) {
                    %>
                    <li><a href="Trabajadores.jsp"> <span
                            class="icon-user-4"></span>
                            Trabajadores
                    </a></li>
                    <%
                    }
                    %>
                    <%
                    if (Sesion.getInstance().get(Parametros.SESION_USUARIO) != null && 
                    ((Usuario) Sesion.getInstance().get(Parametros.SESION_USUARIO)).getIdTipoUsuario().equals(1)) {
                    %>
                    <li><a href="Consultas.jsp"> <span
                            class="icon-star"></span>
                            Consultas
                    </a></li>
                    <%
                    }
                    %>
                    <%
                    if (Sesion.getInstance().get(Parametros.SESION_USUARIO) != null) {
                    %>
                    <li><a href="CerrarSesion.jsp"> <span
                            class="icon-question"></span>
                            Cerrar Sesion
                    </a></li>
                    <%
                    }
                    %>
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix">

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="dashboard-wrapper">
                <div class="left-sidebar">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <div class="widget">
                                <div class="widget-header">
                                    <div class="title">Login</div>
                                    <span class="tools"> <a class="fs1" aria-hidden="true"
                                        data-icon="&#xe090;"></a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="widget-body">
                                    <div class="span3">&nbsp;</div>
                                    <div class="span6">
                                        <div class="sign-in-container">
                                            <s:form action="iniciarSesion" cssStyle="login-wrapper">
                                                <div class="header">
                                                    <div class="row-fluid">
                                                        <div class="span12">
                                                            <h3>
                                                                Iniciar Sesion<img src="Bootstrap/img/logo1.png"
                                                                    alt="Logo" class="pull-right">
                                                            </h3>
                                                            <p>Ingrese con su usuario y clave</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <s:textfield label="Usuario" name="nickname"
                                                    placeholder="Usuario" required="required"
                                                    class="input span12 email"></s:textfield>
                                                <s:password label="Contraseña" name="clave"
                                                    cssClass="input span12 password" placeholder="Contraseña"
                                                    required="required"></s:password>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="actions">
                                            <s:submit cssClass="btn btn-primary bottom-margin"
                                                value="Entrar"></s:submit>
                                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
                                            <div class="errors">
                                                <s:actionerror />
                                            </div>
                                        </s:if>
                                        <s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
                                           <div class="welcome">
                                              <s:actionmessage/>
                                           </div>
                                        </s:if>
                                        </s:form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="span3">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Una anotación: he borrado todos los datos de navegación que pudieran estar haciendo interferencia en ***ambos navegadores***.

Comment: El servidor de aplicaciones y Struts no están asociados al problema principal. El problema que afrontas es que debes estar haciendo muchas peticiones redirect desde tu servidor a una misma página. Puedes verlo como una recursividad infinita, pero en este caso son muchos redirects a sí mismo.

Comment: Solo hago un redirect condicional cuando se entra al index, pero de ahí ya no hago otros redirect.

Comment: Por favor publica las fuentes de esos JSPs también

Comment: Ya están publicadas